# Testing a nativescript application on iOS shows a blank screen after launch screen

Tags: ios, nativescript, testflight

Running using tns run ios works fine on my iPad.
When building and publishing to appstore when I test it using testflight  I see the splash screen and then a blank screen.
Does someone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of NativeScript you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest version: 6.2

Comment: Did you refer device log by connecting it to Xcode? Try to see if it's uncaught JS exception by listening to [uncaughtError](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#use-application-events) event.

Comment: How do I get the device log?
I don't think it's uncaught JS exception as I have tested it before uploading to appstore using tns run ios and everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it.
The reason was trying to write to a read only directory.
A directory under: knownFolders.currentApp();
I found it by connection my iPad to the mac and opening xcode console.
When switched to knownFonlders.documents(); it works.